# How to read data from a file with different column in a line

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I want to read data from a file in which every line has different number of data, e.g.

```
a b c d
e f 
h g k
```

and I need to have format like this `format(T8,<num>(I7))` which `<num>` is dynamic format specifier determined in run time which specified number of column in a row of input file.
This is the code I want to modified. The code worked in Intel fortran, but in gfortran I got error.

```
 do i=1,N
    read(20,'(I7)') CV(i,1)

    backspace(20)
    15 format(T8,CV(i,1)(I7))
    read(20,15) CV(i,2:CV(i,1)+1)
 end do
```

The error message is

```
         15 format(T8,CV(i,1)(I7))
                      1
Error: Unexpected element ‘C’ in format string at (1)
```

Comment: @francescalus  `15 format(T8,CV(i,1)(I7))
Error: Unexpected element ‘C’ in format string at (1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by constructing a format via an **internal write** as follow:

```
character(Len=30) :: form
do i=1,N
    read(20,'(I7)') CV(i,1)
    write( form, '(a,i0,a)' )  '(', CV(i,1), 'i7)'
    backspace(20)
    read(20,form) CV(i,2:CV(i,1)+1)
end do
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a variable format to do this.

When processing an input list, any values required to process an input item are determined when starting to process that item.  In this case, it is possible to use the first item of a line to determine the array elements to be read:

```
read(20, '(*(I7))') CV(i,1), CV(i,2:CV(i,1)+1)
```

The repeat specifier ("number of items to read" aspect) of the format, in this case what is meant by the attempt to use`CV(i,1)`, does not need to match the number of items: it just needs to be greater (in this case `*` meaning "unlimited").  When the all of the items in the list have been read processing stops.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the BACKSPACE, which can be really time consuming, I often prefer to read input into a character line, which I can then analyse quickly. In your specific case, as the number of input data are always given as data item 1 the answer given by @francescalus is perfectly fine. If the lines vary more drastically you could expand the following code (which currently does just your example)

```
program read_data
! 
integer, parameter :: MAX_DATA=10
integer, parameter :: MAX_ROWS=4
integer :: ios
integer :: i
character(len=18+7*MAX_DATA) :: line
integer, dimension(MAX_ROWS, MAX_DATA) :: cv
!
cv(:,:) = 0
open(unit=20, file='data.txt')
main_loop: do i=1, 4
  read(20, '(a)', iostat=ios) line
  if(is_iostat_end(ios)) exit main_loop
  read(line(1:len_trim(line)),'(*(i2))', iostat=ios) cv(i,1), cv(i,2:cv(i,1)+1)
  if(.not.(ios==0 .or. is_iostat_end(ios))) exit main_loop
  write(*,*) i,cv(i,1), cv(i,1:6)
enddo main_loop
!
end program read_data
```